# Задача на вывод среднего числа из 3-х введённых

Tags: javascript

Отдельно варианты работают. Не могу понять как их в единый механизм запилить. Задача такова - 1. Составить алгоритм вывода среднего по значению из трёх чисел в виде блок-схемы. Все числа разные
Вход: три числа
Выход: среднее число(которое по значению находится между другими двумя).
Блок схема - http://d.pr/i/1kflp

```js
<script>
a=+prompt("Введите число:"); 
b=+prompt("Введите число:"); 
c=+prompt("Введите число:");
 
 if (a>b) (b<c)
 var d = b;
 alert(d);

  if (a<b) (a>c)
  var d = a;
  alert(d);

   if (c<a) (c>b)
   var d = c;
   alert(d);
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Вывод среднего числа</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
a=+prompt("Введите число:"); 
b=+prompt("Введите число:"); 
c=+prompt("Введите число:");
 
 if (a>b) (b<c)
 var d = b;
 alert(d);

  if (a<b) (a>c)
  var d = a;
  alert(d);

   if (c<a) (c>b)
   var d = c;
   alert(d);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: пропустили логический оператор

Comment: и фигурные скобки

Comment: и круглые невпопад стоят

Comment: ну фигурные и не обязательно :-)

Comment: @Grundy, обязательно при таком коде.

Comment: @Grundy, а зачем мне три раза в выводе одно и то же число?

Comment: @BOPOH а почему одно и то же? оно может поменяться после каждого сравнения :-) но может и нет

Comment: @Grundy, условия взаимоисключающие, поэтому если сработало одно - другие не сработают, без фигурных скобок alert в итоге будет три раза, правда, если средним будет число c, тогда два прошлых алерта будут ерунду показывать, а оно мне надо?

Comment: @BOPOH, ну это уже другой вопрос :-)

Answer (score 3):

ES6:

```
alert(Array.from({length:3}).map(x => +prompt("Введите число")).sort((a,b) => a-b)[1])
```

Comment: 6-ть раз программа предлагает ввести число а надо что бы предлагало ввести 3 числа и программа выводила из этих чисел среднее.

Comment: @RastefanoTafaray, нет. Какой браузер?

Comment: браузер Google Chrome а в safari вообще ничего не работает((

Comment: @RastefanoTafaray, я же написал, ES6. В хроме 6 prompt'ов быть не может. И вообще, там ниже уже какой-то ответ есть.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Вывод среднего числа</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
a=+prompt("Введите число:"); 
b=+prompt("Введите число:"); 
c=+prompt("Введите число:");

    if ((a>b) && (b<c)) {
    var d = b;
    alert(d);
    } else if ((a<b) && (a>c)) {
        var d = a;
        alert(d);
    } else if( (c<a) && (c>b) ){
        var d = c;
        alert(d);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: (a > b) is not a function(…)`

Comment: первый коммент к вопросу посмотрите - это тоже надо было сделать + у вас с ветками else напутано, это вообще не должно работать

Comment: так и есть этот вариант не работает((( и вот интересно почему.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>
a=parseInt(prompt("a:")); 
b=parseInt(prompt("b:")); 
c=parseInt(prompt("c:")); 
if((b<a && a<c) || (c<a && a<b)) alert(a);
if((a<b && b<c) || (c<b && b<a)) alert(b);
if((a<c && c<b) || (b<c && c<a)) alert(c); 
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Вывод среднего числа</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
a=parseInt(prompt("a:")); 
b=parseInt(prompt("b:")); 
c=parseInt(prompt("c:")); 
if((b<a && a<c) || (c<a && a<b)) alert(a);
if((a<b && b<c) || (c<b && b<a)) alert(b);
if((a<c && c<b) || (b<c && c<a)) alert(c); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```